# How to insert white spaces as input into char array with std::cin

Tags: c++

I know that I can use :

```
std::string s; 
std::getline(std::cin,s);
```

to make white spaces readable in a string how about char arrays?

Comment: `istream::getline` accepts a char array parameter.

Comment: Did you try using `std::getline` with char arrays? What happened?

Comment: is the syntax the same whether I use a char array?

Comment: Perhaps you can find something in [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip)?

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: Sure ... I'm just not sure what the problem you have is just yet. Give it a try and ask for advice afterwards if you don't get the result you want.

Comment: I mean what is the syntax of getline if I use a characters array instead of a std::string?

Comment: They are two different functions. `std::getline` is a free function, `std::istream::getline` is a member function. You must read about them as separate functions. They are not related - even though the name suggests they are.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might use `std::cin` or `std::getline` function twice more.

So, if then, you should make `std::cin` clear.
If there are trash values in `std::cin`, then `std::getline` might not work.

So, why don't you try this?

```
std::string s;

std::cout << "Input:";
std::cin.clear()
std::getline(std::cin, s)
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

OR

You can also use the member function of `std::cin` for char array.

```
char s[1000] = '\0';

std::cout << "Input: ";
std::cin.getline(s, 1000);
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) member of an `istream` such as `std::cin`, like this:

```cpp
char a[80];
std::cin.getline(a, 80);
```

You can also pass in a 3rd argument which is a delimiter character, and the stream will stop reading when that character is reached.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W6K1aj)